# How to toggle Sidebar Component in Header with a Burger Menu using Hooks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, sidebar

I am very new in React and maybe someone could help me.
I want to toggle my Sidebar in my Header Component with Hooks.

This is my Code:

**Sidebar.js**

```
...imported things
...styles

export const SideBar = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <StyledSideBar>
      <Tooltip title="Dashboard" placement="right" arrow >
        <StyledButton onClick={() => history.push('/dashboard')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTachometerAltFast} />
        </StyledButton>
      </Tooltip >
      <Tooltip title="Chat" placement="right" arrow>
        <StyledButton onClick={() => history.push('/chat')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCommentsAlt} />
        </StyledButton>
      </Tooltip>
      <Tooltip title="Calendar" placement="right" arrow>
        <StyledButton onClick={() => history.push('/calendar')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendarAlt} />
        </StyledButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </StyledSideBar>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

**Header.js**

```
...imported things
...styles
import SideBar from '../sidebar';

export const MainHeader = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setShow(!show);

  return (
  <AppBar elevation={2} position="sticky" color="inherit" >
    <FlexToolbar variant="regular">
      <StyledMenuIcon open={show} onClick={toggle.{SideBar}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
      </StyledMenuIcon>
      <Logo src="/assets/images/logo.svg" alt="Vetera Sky" />
      <BreakpointLogo src="/assets/images/get-started-icon.svg" alt="Vetera Sky" />
      <Spacer />
      <LogoutButton onClick={onLogout}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff} />
        <Typography variant="label" color={actionSecondary}>Logout</Typography>
      </LogoutButton>
      <BreakpointLogoutButton onClick={onLogout}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff} />
      </BreakpointLogoutButton>
    </FlexToolbar>
  </AppBar>

  )};

export default MainHeader;
```

I know this is wrong, but i could not find anything in the Web or in here.
If the StyledMenuIcon is clicked once, the Sidebar should open on the left and if clicked again it should close.

Hope someone can help me soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You should move your state higher up in the tree where both MainHeader and SideBar components can use it:

```
function App() {
    const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(false);

    const onToggleSidebar = () => {
        setShowSidebar(!showSidebar);
    };

    return (
        <MainHeader onToggleSidebar={onToggleSidebar} />
        <SideBar open={showSidebar}
    );
}
```

If the components aren't available on the same level in the tree, you could use React's context api to use this logic from different places down the tree.

Or if you're already using something like redux or another state management system you could move your app state there.